# In an inner product space, can we have $\langle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n,y\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x_n,y\rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

In an inner product space $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, we have $\langle x_1+x_2,y\rangle=\langle x_1,y\rangle+\langle x_2,y\rangle$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is convergent in $X$, then can we have $\langle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n,y\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle x_n,y\rangle$?

Edit: If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: Yes, this is always true, since the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is continuous. In fact, this map is Lipschitz-continuous in each entry. This can be seen using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Exactly what part of the proof is unclear to you? Using the fact that $\langle \cdot, y\rangle$ is continuous and linear it should be straightforward.

Comment: @Stefen Perko I proved $<\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n,y>=<x,y>$ but could not prove $\sum <x_n,y>=<x,y>$

Comment: I don't know what $x$ is. If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ converges, then so does $\lim_{n\to \infty} \langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,y\rangle$ s.t. $\langle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, y\rangle = \lim_{n\to \infty} \langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,y\rangle$. Then $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \langle \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,y\rangle =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n\langle x_i,y\rangle$